# how to remove blank rows in constituent summary report?

Tags: reports

Civi 5.15.1, Wordpress 5.2.3

When I run a Constituent Summary report having selected the default columns (none) and default filter (deceased=No), I get a page and a half of squished, blank rows at the beginning. Some filters remove them, other filters don't. Not sure what other info may be relevant. Does anyone know the cause and solution, or could advise how to troubleshoot? I'd prefer not to have to figure out a workaround using the Search functionality. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Selecting the Contact ID and Date Modified columns unsquished the rows, so I was able to delete the offending Contact IDs from civicrm_contact using phpMyAdmin, without triggering any FK violations. The report now looks normal, though I'd still be curious to know how 85 null contacts got added (all at once). Has anyone come across this before?